# ViewPager not showing page content / not refreshing after changing the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager / FragmentPagerAdapter in one of my application fragments to display different listviews in each page (see the picture below) :
[image]

The problem is that after i change the current view (Fragment) and i reopen it again, the listview isn't rendered (see the picture below) :

[image]

The behaviour is random, sometimes the listview are shown when i slide between different tabs/pages.

Here is my fragment code :

```
public class AstucesFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public static String[] tabslist = new String[5];

    public AstucesFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_astuces, container, false);

        tabslist[0] = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.astuces_quotidien);
        tabslist[1] = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.astuces_resto);
        tabslist[2] = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.astuces_loisirs);
        tabslist[3] = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.astuces_transports);
        tabslist[4] = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.astuces_tous);

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.astuces_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(R.layout.fragment_astuces_tabs_quotidien)
                        .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(R.layout.fragment_astuces_tabs_resto)
                        .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(R.layout.fragment_astuces_tabs_loisirs)
                        .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(R.layout.fragment_astuces_tabs_transports)
                        .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setCustomView(R.layout.fragment_astuces_tabs_tous)
                        .setTabListener(this));

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.i("AstucesFragment","onTabSelected()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.i("AstucesFragment","onTabReselected()");
    }


    /**
     * A {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Log.i("AppSectionsPagerAdapter","Page ID : "+i);
            // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
            Fragment fragment = new AstucesListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(AstucesListFragment.ARG_PAGE_CAT, tabslist[i]);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabslist.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabslist[position];
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class AstucesListFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_PAGE_CAT = "page_cat";

        private List<Astuce> astuceList = new ArrayList<Astuce>();
        private ListView listView;
        private AstuceAdapter adapter;
        private AstuceDAO astuceDAO;

        public AstucesListFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_astuces_page, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();

            Log.i("AstucesListFragment","onCreateView()");


            String theme = "";
            if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_quotidien)) theme = "Q";
            else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_resto)) theme = "R";
            else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_loisirs)) theme = "L";
            else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_transports)) theme = "T";
            else theme = "";


            astuceDAO = new AstuceDAO();
            astuceList = astuceDAO.findAstuceByTheme(theme);

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.astuces_list);
            adapter = new AstuceAdapter(getActivity(), astuceList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**How can i fix this problem ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you want your fragments to maintain its state even after changing the tabs,
   Try this,

   mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); //as you have 5 fragments

But this will make the activity to initialize all the fragments at the same time when the activity is invoked.

2. Another method is to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. Refer,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: I tried both :
- mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
- FragmentStatePagerAdapter
and it works , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing strings correctly. When comparing two strings you need to use equals() method instead of == operator. So in `onCreateView()` in `AstucesListFragment` replace

```
if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_quotidien)) theme = "Q";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_resto)) theme = "R";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_loisirs)) theme = "L";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT) == getString(R.string.astuces_transports)) theme = "T";
else theme = "";
```

with

```
if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT).equals(getString(R.string.astuces_quotidien))) theme = "Q";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT).equals( getString(R.string.astuces_resto))) theme = "R";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT).equals( getString(R.string.astuces_loisirs))) theme = "L";
else if (args.getString(ARG_PAGE_CAT).equals( getString(R.string.astuces_transports))) theme = "T";
else theme = "";
```

This may solve your problem as the results of == operators will be inconsistent as both the strings may or may not point to same object.